# How to center a map on the active marker with Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I try to center a map on the active marker with Leaflet (version 1.7.1). For that, when I create a marker, I add an event:

```
function addMarkerTomap(map) {
...
var result = L.marker(lat,lng],{icon:myIcon}.addTo(map).on(`click', centerMap);
...
}
```

Note that map is a parameter, not a global variable.
Now I define the centerMap function:

```
function centerMap(e) {
   map.panTo(e.LatLng);
}
```

As you guess, map is undefined in centerMap.
I tried that:

```
var result = L.marker(lat,lng],{icon:myIcon}.addTo(map).on(`click', centerMap(map));
```

and

```
function centerMap(map,e) {
   map.panTo(e.LatLng);
}
```

But that doesn't work !
Any idea how to call the function with a parameter ?

Thank you by advance,

Note 1: If I do:

```
function addMarkerTomap(map) {
...
var result = L.marker(lat,lng],{icon:myIcon}.addTo(map).on('click', function(e){map.panTo(e.LatLng);});
...
}
```

That doesn't work !

Note 2: if I do:

```
map.panTo(e.latlng)
```

click on the marker: the popup window is displayed but the map is not centered, a second click and the map is centered but the popup is closed !
Probably because the click cannot opend the popup AND execute the panTo in same time.

Note 3: I tried to center the map when the popup is open:

```
result.binPopup(popup,options).on('popupopen',function(popup){map.panTo(popup.getLatLng);});
```

That also doesn't work !

Comment: So `.on('click', centerMap);` would be correct but be sure that you use `'` . Also the property of the event is lowercase: `map.panTo(e.latlng);`

Comment: yes, that was a typo fault ! but that doesn't work